# Why php artisan make: test PostTest --unit command creates a new test extends not from Tests\TestCase, but from PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase? Laravel 8

Tags: unit-testing, laravel-8, laravel-artisan, test-environments

The test environment is enabled in the

```
Tests\TestCase
```

class via the

```
createApplication()
```

method, but not in the

```
PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
```

class.

So why then when the artisan creates a new test that extends from

```
PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
```

class?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it all out!

When create a unitest with

```
php artisan make:test MyTest --unit
```

command.

Such tests should not affect the database. Therefore, it is not necessary to change the environment for such tests.

And so the test class extends from the

```
PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
```

class.

But if create a test without the --unit flag

Then the test class extends from the

```
Tests\TestCase
```

class, which leads to automatic execution of the

```
createApplication()
```

method and a change in the environment.